What exactly is a segmentation fault in C?
For a project in my IT class I have to implement a sponge construction (doesn't have to be secure).
#include <stdio.h>

int tab[] = {129, 160, 71, 24, 142, 254, 178, 152, 182, 53, 190, 133, 149, 187, 56, 14, 198, 62, 192, 118, 121, 4, 125, 146, 90, 207, 66, 31, 19, 7, 132, 114, 68, 202, 208, 80, 37, 40, 134, 58, 111, 42, 250, 105, 180, 41, 156, 155, 166, 211, 170, 215, 165, 69, 88, 23, 6, 141, 226, 186, 35, 28, 54, 193, 89, 92, 230, 120, 44, 59, 64, 237, 151, 91, 116, 171, 87, 115, 26, 137, 67, 78, 194, 5, 29, 167, 189, 17, 253, 124, 238, 65, 184, 30, 185, 220, 84, 172, 123, 174, 18, 117, 153, 150, 128, 74, 162, 98, 212, 231, 159, 242, 206, 93, 188, 46, 76, 243, 147, 240, 219, 179, 139, 246, 255, 130, 195, 99, 161, 183, 245, 22, 140, 45, 173, 163, 148, 33, 20, 47, 216, 131, 12, 72, 223, 32, 145, 94, 249, 96, 205, 10, 157, 57, 95, 136, 138, 218, 229, 0, 122, 107, 126, 113, 109, 127, 158, 168, 210, 236, 204, 112, 191, 252, 104, 48, 73, 79, 197, 52, 108, 176, 38, 102, 100, 164, 247, 61, 2, 241, 43, 224, 119, 75, 63, 25, 143, 225, 97, 217, 106, 203, 110, 49, 200, 1, 39, 233, 3, 214, 81, 209, 60, 244, 34, 154, 239, 9, 101, 232, 235, 85, 83, 50, 86, 169, 51, 222, 251, 175, 144, 135, 16, 70, 248, 15, 82, 234, 27, 228, 8, 55, 21, 221, 36, 196, 177, 77, 227, 199, 213, 13, 201, 11, 103, 181};

int status[208];

void mixRows_gerade_runde_(int *liste, int *result) {
    result[0] = (liste[0] ^ 0xd3);
    result[1] = (liste[1] ^ liste[0] ^ 0xd3);
    result[2] = (liste[2] ^ liste[1] ^ liste[0] ^ 0xd3);
    result[3] = (liste[3] ^ liste[2] ^ liste[1] ^ liste[0] ^ 0xd3);
    result[4] = (liste[4] ^ 0xd4);
    result[5] = (liste[5] ^ liste[4] ^ 0xd4);
    result[6] = (liste[6] ^ liste[5] ^ liste[4] ^ 0xd4);
    result[7] = (liste[7] ^ liste[6] ^ liste[5] ^ liste[4] ^ 0xd4);
    result[8] = (liste[8] ^ 0xd5);
    result[9] = (liste[9] ^ liste[8] ^ 0xd5);
    result[10] = (liste[10] ^ liste[9] ^ liste[8] ^ 0xd5);
    result[11] = (liste[11] ^ liste[10] ^ liste[9] ^ liste[8] ^ 0xd5);
    result[12] = (liste[12] ^ 0xd6);
    result[13] = (liste[12] ^ liste[13] ^ 0xd6);
    result[14] = (liste[12] ^ liste[13] ^ liste[14] ^ 0xd6);
    result[15] = (liste[12] ^ liste[13] ^ liste[14] ^ liste[15] ^ 0xd6);
}

void mixRows_ungerade_runde_(int *liste, int *result) {
    result[0] = (liste[3] ^ liste[2] ^ liste[1] ^ liste[0] ^ 0xd3);
    result[1] = (liste[3] ^ liste[2] ^ liste[1] ^ 0xd3);
    result[2] = (liste[3] ^ liste[2] ^ 0xd3);
    result[3] = (liste[3] ^ 0xd3);
    result[4] = (liste[7] ^ liste[6] ^ liste[5] ^ liste[4] ^ 0xd4);
    result[5] = (liste[5] ^ liste[7] ^ liste[6] ^ 0xd4);
    result[6] = (liste[7] ^ liste[6] ^ 0xd4);
    result[7] = (liste[7] ^ 0xd4);
    result[8] = (liste[8] ^ liste[9] ^ liste[10] ^ liste[11] ^ 0xd5);
    result[9] = (liste[9] ^ liste[11] ^ liste[10] ^ 0xd5);
    result[10] = (liste[10] ^ liste[11] ^ 0xd5);
    result[11] = (liste[11] ^ 0xd5);
    result[12] = (liste[12] ^ liste[13] ^ liste[14] ^ liste[15] ^ 0xd6);
    result[13] = (liste[13] ^ liste[14] ^ liste[15] ^ 0xd6);
    result[14] = (liste[14] ^ liste[15] ^ 0xd6);
    result[15] = (liste[15] ^ 0xd6);
}

void liste_zu_status(int *list) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
        status[i] ^= list[i];
    }
}

void subbytes(int *list, int *result) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
        result[i] = tab[list[i]];
    }
}

void shift_colums(int *list, int *result) {
    result[0] = list[0];
    result[1] = list[13];
    result[2] = list[10];
    result[3] = list[7];
    result[4] = list[4];
    result[5] = list[1];
    result[6] = list[14];
    result[7] = list[11];
    result[8] = list[8];
    result[9] = list[5];
    result[10] = list[2];
    result[11] = list[15];
    result[12] = list[12];
    result[13] = list[9];
    result[14] = list[6];
    result[15] = list[3];
}

void prp(int *block, int *result) {
    int temp[16];
    subbytes(block, temp);
    mixRows_gerade_runde_(temp, result);
    shift_colums(result, temp);
    subbytes(temp, result);
    mixRows_gerade_runde_(result, temp);
    shift_colums(temp, result);
    subbytes(result, temp);
    mixRows_ungerade_runde_(temp, result);
    shift_colums(result, temp);
    subbytes(temp, result);
    mixRows_ungerade_runde_(result, temp);
    shift_colums(temp, result);
    subbytes(temp, result);
    mixRows_ungerade_runde_(result, temp);
    shift_colums(temp, result);
    subbytes(temp, result);
}

void status_permutieren() {
    int temp[16];
    for (int i = 0; i < 208; i += 16) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 16; j++) {
            status[i + j] ^= status[i - 16 + j];
            temp[j] = status[i + j];
        }
        prp(temp, &status[i]);
    }
}

void block_absorbieren(int *block) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
        status[i] ^= block[i];
    }
    status_permutieren();
}

void status_zuruecksetzen() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 208; i++) {
        status[i] = 0;
    }
}

void daten_absorbieren(int *daten, int len) {
    int temp[16];
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i += 16) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 16; j++) {
            temp[j] = (i + j < len) ? daten[i + j] : 0;
        }
        block_absorbieren(temp);
    }
}

void daten_generieren(int menge, int *ergebnis) {
    for (int i = 0; i < menge; i++) {
        ergebnis[i] = status[207] ^ status[206] ^ ~status[202] & status[197] | status[196] ^ status[189];
        status_permutieren();
    }
}

int main() {
    printf("starting");
    // Initialize status array with zeros
    for (int i = 0; i < 208; i++) {
        status[i] = 0;
    }

    // Example usage
    int data[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16};
    int generated_data[10];

    // Absorb data
    daten_absorbieren(data, sizeof(data) / sizeof(data[0]));

    // Generate data
    daten_generieren(10, generated_data);

    // Print generated data
    printf("Generated data:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        printf("%d ", generated_data[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}

The program exits with code=3221225477, and when I debug I get this message:
Exception has occurred.
Segmentation fault

on this line of code:
void subbytes(int *list, int *result) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
        result[i] = tab[list[i]];//<-this line
    }
}

I had no idea what to try, because the code seemed fine to me...

line 100:36: runtime error: index -16 out of bounds for type 'int [208]' - (that is status[i + j] ^= status[i - 16 + j];) -   When i and j are both 0, then status[i - 16 + j]  will try to access status[-16]. Boom. If you have gcc, compile with -g -fsanitize=address,undefined and then re-run the program. It's a brilliant tool for finding the cause for issues like this.

Unrelated: I would use parentheses on this line: ergebnis[i] = status[207] ^ status[206] ^ ~status[202] & status[197] | status[196] ^ status[189]; to clarify that you actually mean it to be interpreted like this: ergebnis[i] = (status[207] ^ status[206] ^ (~status[202] & status[197])) | (status[196] ^ status[189]);

The use of terms is a little bit confusing here. Segmentation fault is mostly a term used by Unix-like OS, corresponding to the event SIGSEGV in signal.h. You are however clearly using Windows, where the equivalent term is "Access violation". The magic numer 3221225477 means nothing at all before you convert it to hex, 0xC0000005. Then you can look up what that Windows error code means - it means access violation. What compiler & debugger are you using?

A segmentation fault is not a C thing. Rather, it is a signal that your process receives on certain operating systems that have a notion of signals, such as Linux (or any POSIX-compatible system).
A signal is generally something that the OS kernel "sends" to a process to interrupt the process's normal operation; this is typically done at a kernelspace to userspace transition (e.g. when returning from a system call).
In this case, what happens is that the CPU executes some invalid instruction (namely an invalid memory access). This causes it to execute a CPU exception (maybe "page fault"), which transitions the CPU into kernel mode. The kernel starts executing, notices that the CPU has complained about a process causing a page fault, and upon consulting its memory management bookkeeping data, the kernel decides that your process did something bad with memory (perhaps "violating the memory segmentation rules"), and so it resumes your process userspace code with a "segmentation fault" signal (SIGSEGV). That's because the kernel knows that the currently executing instruction of the process cannot be executed (because the CPU said so), so the process cannot resume there; instead, it resumed in the registered signal handler if there is one, or it terminates.
If you do install a signal handler for SIGSEGV but don't make it fix the bad memory access, your program might just loop forever trying to execute the faulting instruction over and over.
But this has nothing to do with C per se. The problem is that your code contains an instruction that cannot be correctly executed. A debugger should be able to point out the precise instruction that caused the signal, and you should be able to trace back from there where your code went wrong.
[Update:] I forgot to mention "synchronous" vs "asynchronous" signals: A synchronous signal is a direct result of the code's execution, such as the SIGSEGV in question here, or a SIGILL if you hit a bad instruction, or a SIGTRAP if you hit a debug instruction, or SIGFPE for division by zero, say, of if call raise. The corresponding signal handler (if any) for a synchronous signal is called in the causing thread, and precisely at the causing instruction. By contrast, an asynchronous signal is not related to the executing code, and could be sent e.g. from some other process (via kill, say), and may be delivered at some arbitrary point whenever the kernel decides it's time to interrupt your process (e.g. on a timer interrupt). In that case, the current instruction in your code at the point of receiving the signal is more or less meaningless. To tie this back to your question: The SIGSEGV you receive is almost certainly a synchronous signal caused by your code doing something invalid, but it could also be that someone just deliberately sent you the signal asynchronously.

"A debugger should be able to point out the precise instruction that caused the signal" - it is a very optimistic assumption :). It would be great

@0___________: at the machine instruction level, this should hopefully be true, since the SIGSEGV in question is a synchronous signal (which I had really meant to mention). Whether you can connect the instruction to source code is of course a different matter :-) (e.g. it could be in generated code, just to make things extra hard).
